# Execute add_filter inside add_action or is it possible to combine them?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, add-action

I need to add a script to the footer if a product is added to the cart. When a product is added, it goes to the checkout page. So here on the checkout page, I need to insert the script. (Only once, when added. It will not show up after reloading the page.)

```
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'clearlocal' );
function clearlocal(){
  add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_cart_item_data', 'wdm_empty_cart', 10,  3);
  function wdm_empty_cart( $cart_item_data, $product_id, $variation_id ) {
     global $woocommerce;
     //Check if product ID is in a certain category
     if( has_term( 'packages', 'product_cat', $product_id ) ){
         ?><script type="text/javascript"> localStorage.clear();
         </script><?php
     }
     //Do nothing with the data and return
     return $cart_item_data;
  }
}
```

If a product is added from the category called packages, then I need to add the script. But I need it only when added, not always as soon as the product is in the cart.

If my goal is to show a message. Then it works just as I need.

```
  add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_cart_item_data', 'wdm_empty_cart', 10,  3);
  function wdm_empty_cart( $cart_item_data, $product_id, $variation_id ) {
    global $woocommerce;
    //Check if product ID is in a certain category
    if( has_term( 'packages', 'product_cat', $product_id ) ){
        wc_add_notice('Some texts','success');
    }
    //Do nothing with the data and return
    return $cart_item_data;
  }
```

I think the problem is add_filter is not working with add_action. I also tried this but did not work.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_cart_item_data', 'wdm_empty_cart', 10,  3);
function wdm_empty_cart( $cart_item_data, $product_id, $variation_id ) {
 global $woocommerce;
 //Check if product ID is in a certain category
 if( has_term( 'packages', 'product_cat', $product_id ) ){
     add_action( 'wp_footer', 'clearlocal' );
     function clearlocal(){
     ?><script type="text/javascript"> localStorage.clear();
     </script><?php
 }
 }
 //Do nothing with the data and return
 return $cart_item_data;
}
```

Comment: I believe it would be better to use `wc_enqueue_js` and use an [anonymous function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php) for your add_action.

Comment: Thank you. Can you give some examples?

Answer (score 1):

Use [wc_enqueue_js](https://woocommerce.github.io/code-reference/namespaces/default.html#function_wc_enqueue_js)

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_cart_item_data', 'he_check_empty_cart', 10,  3);
function he_check_empty_cart( $cart_item_data, $product_id, $variation_id ) {
    //Check if product ID is in a certain category.
    if( has_term( 'packages', 'product_cat', $product_id ) ){
        wc_enqueue_js(' localStorage.clear();' );
        }
    }
    //Do nothing with the data and return.
    return $cart_item_data;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. wc_enqueue_js is working itself but inside a function, it does not work.

Comment: That is exactly the purpose of wc_enqueue_js. Are you sure you're condition is correct?

Comment: I understand the problem. I redirect to the checkout page after adding the cart. So without redirecting it works. But with `woocommerce_add_to_cart_redirect` it does not work.

Comment: You should look at triggering this with another hook. If this can fire on `woocommerce_before_checkout_form` or some other action, as opposed to a filter.

Comment: I found another way to achieve my goal. When clicking the add to cart button, a script is adding.
`<?php if ( is_product() && has_term( 'packages', 'product_cat' ) ) {

echo '<script>
$(".add_to_cart_button").click(function(){
  $.getScript("/script.js");
});


</script>';


} ?>`